# Table delete and write operation at the same time

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a application which is continiously inserting data to Table1.
I have one more python application which reads data (every 20 seconds )from Table1 and inserts into Merge_table (new one) and delete the row in Tabe1 that are inserted.
I taught there is row level locking. looks sqlite3 there is no row level locking.
Can suggestions how I can overcome this so that both will happen without any issues.

2) I need to clean the Table1 as it will be come huge.

```
Error I see when inserting data:
Error: database is locked
```

Code I am using the delete data

```
delete from MyTable where ID between 1 and 50.
```

I read we cannot have multiple write operations. what is the other option

Comment: I'm not sure you will achieve what you want with sqlite. Although it might be possible to slow down the inserts to allow time for the read/delete to happen. Even if you do this you'll need to handle the exceptions raised when the database is locked (both for the reader and the writer)

Comment: what is the suggestion you can provide me? should I use mysql. with that I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Yes, if you can change to MySQL using InnoDB tables it would use [row level locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-locking.html#internal-row-level-locking)

Comment: can I use sqlite community edition I get default in ubantu to get this functionality

Comment: I've consolidated my comments in to an answer to avoid a long discussion in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you will achieve what you want with sqlite.

You could slow down the inserts to allow time for the read/delete to happen, but even if you do this you'll need to handle the exceptions raised when the database is locked (both for the reader and the writer).

Another possibility is to use sqlite in [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) but be sure its limitations are not a problem for you; for example in WAL mode your application must be "...willing to sacrifice durability following a power loss or hard reboot." Just make sure you read the documentation carefully.

The next thing option is to move to another database server, such as MySQL. With InnoDB tables record locking is available, rather than table locking.

Sqlite is great, I have a database with almost 9 millions rows in a table, but it's not good with concurrent writes - that's when you really need a database server.